# How to install python 2.6 on CentoOS?

Tags: centos, python

I am new to linux. I want to install Python 2.6 on CentOS. How can I intall them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has been answered on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465036/install-python-2-6-in-centos). Hope this fits your needs.